# How do I update the existing documents' schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to do some MongoDB operations.

At the beginning the category was number,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const sampleSchema = new Schema({
 category: {
    type: Number,
 }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("SampleSchema", sampleSchema);
```

Now the category changed to String, So I changed the model like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const sampleSchema = new Schema({
 category: {
    type: String,
 }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("SampleSchema", sampleSchema);
```

The problem is, I have already inserted 200 records into this collection. Is there any way to update the category value with a string and change its type to string?

Comment: You can try this approach. Change the `category` field type to [mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed). Then run an update on the collection to transform the number value to string. Once, done you can change the field type to what yu really want - string.

Comment: That's worked , Thanks @prasad_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `category` to `mixed`, that's working fine with numbers and string.

Thanks for the help @prasad_

Answer (score 1):

Please get All data by query and update it one by one in loop.

Like:

```
db.tableName.find( { 'status' : { $type : 1 } } ).forEach( function (val) {   
  val.status = new String(val.status);
  db.tableName.save(val);
});
```

Comment: Is this work as an update or create new records?

Comment: This will update existing records in collection.